# Magento Debug Tools Questionnaire

Tags: discussion

I am a university student doing my final year project looking at improving Magento developer/debug tools and have a [questionnaire](http://goo.gl/forms/IaBDbA4RXO) that I would like to ask developers who use Magento to complete.

At the end of the [questionnaire](http://goo.gl/forms/IaBDbA4RXO) there is a link to see a summary of what others have said which may be of interest.

The questionnaire will close 2 weeks from today.

If you can think of other forums where I could ask for participants then please add them as an answer.

Thanks.

Edit:
Unfortunately I left FireGento out of the questionnaire and as there have already been some responses it is too late to add it.  If you use FireGento please find somewhere to say so.

Comment: Will you share your findings with the community? That would be great!

Comment: Try it on Twitter! #realmagento

Comment: Great, looking forward to see the results.

Comment: @SanderMangel will do

Comment: Awesome question.Unfortunately this question is not belong here. But we love to hear your findings.

Comment: The results are now [available](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1e1ztnRgEErGkPnJvh7Nn74p_AUYRATXy7WmwK7ld_CY/viewanalytics)